# Bubbling drylok

Tags: basement

I drylocked my basement walls just over a year ago.  Basement has been dry since.  Just noticed on a wall a 10 ft section that has some bubbling.  I'm guessing it's moisture from the other side of the wall pushing out the paint.  Do I just leave it be, or scrape off and re apply?  Problem is my deck is on the other side of the wall....no way to solve the problem permanently so it could just happen again

Comment: Moisture shouldn't cause bubbling in a product designed to manage moisture. Something was wrong with the application, methinks. Was the wall dusty or greasy? Why did you apply the product in the first place (do you expect moisture again)?

Comment: When ai bought the house, there was a note that the basement at one time had water in it from a massive storm.  I did a job outside on the grading and it's been dry now for 2 years.  Planning on finishing the basement so figured I would put the drylok on before painting the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet, given your constraints of not really being able to solve the problem for good without taking your deck off...

Identify a time of year when the "bubbles" are not evidently full of water (you want to give the paint the best chance to cure before it's stressed by renewed water pressure.) Put on a dust mask, possibly seal off the area with plastic and tape, and wire-wheel the wall very aggressively - or grind it. You want fresh, clean concrete.

Then repaint.